# iTunes slide down effect

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes

In iTunes when you select a music video and then tap the preview button the modal view and underlying view slides down which makes the movie player visible.

How can this be done?

[image: iTunes]

Answer (score 1):

If all your views (not the movie player) are inside a view controller called `bigController`, here's what do try.

Firstly, add the movie player in the background.  Assuming you are using the `MPMoviePlayerController` class, this is what to do:

```
[bigController.view insertSubview:moviePlayerController atIndex:0];
```

Then animate the other stuff away:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    for (UIView *view in [bigController subviews]) {
        if (view != moviePlayerController.view) {
            view.frame = CGRectMake(0, bigController.view.frame.size.height,
                                       view.frame.size.width,
                                       view.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Well ok that slides down my view controller, but what about the Tabbar? And how would you get the movie player underneath those views? Thnx.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you put everything except the movie player (this includes the tab bar) inside one big controller.  If that doesn't work, you can also move the tab bar down inside the animation block.  I'll post some code in an edit to handle the movie player.

Comment: Try the new code.  And I decided to put the movies player inside the great big controller.

Answer (score 0):

Normally these sort of transitions (fade in/outs, slide in/out) are done by using a timer which gradually resizes the views in/out.  I don't know of a more elegant way of doing it in Cocoa (though there might be one), but doing it yourself really isn't very hard.  Just create a timer with an interval of 50ms or so (you'll probably need a bit of experimentation with the time interval/resize rates to get it smooth), then each time the timer fires, make the movie player view slightly larger until you get it to the size you need. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but using a timer is definitely not the way to do it in Cocoa.